# Requeue JMS request with Mule

Tags: queue, jms, mule, activemq-classic

I use a `JMS component` with Mule for queues with `ActiveMQ` and I want that if a **request is queued fails**, it return to the queue to **retry** the last.

What should I configure to do that in Anypoint Studio?

Comment: Hi, can you be more clear. You have a consumer processing a message and if the process fails you want to don't ack the message and leave it to the queue ?

Comment: Sorry, That the message that failed, return to the queue again, but the last position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just requeueing your message doesn't sound like a good idea, imagine that you have a message that allways fails, this would then in a sense cause an endless recursion while trying to process the message.

It sounds more like what you are interested is the [Rollback Exception Strategy](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/rollback-exception-strategy). With this you can specify a maximum number of redeliveries and when that number is exceeded you could put the message on a `DLQ`(Dead letter queue) or similiar and preferably notify somebody about the failed message.

> You can define a rollback exception strategy to ensure that a message that throws an exception in a flow is rolled back for reprocessing. Use a rollback exception strategy when you cannot correct an error when it occurs in a flow. Usually, you use a rollback exception strategy to handle errors that occur in a flow that involve a transaction. If the transaction fails, that is, if a message throws an exception while being processed, then the rollback exception strategy rolls back the transaction in the flow. If the inbound connector is transactional, Mule delivers the message to the inbound connector of the parent flow again to reattempt processing (that is, message redelivery).

Comment: Do you recommend it or is better to use : Route the Initial-State Message to the Dead Letter Queue?

Comment: @mikedev If a message is at a point where it will not be able to be delivered, you will want to notify someone about it. You will also want to persist the message somewhere so you can resend it, that would be the purpose of the DLQ.

Comment: @mikedev [this](http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html) might be interesting